# Forloop + regex works to find and replace numerics but not bracket in dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame 'energy' in python with column 'Country' with a list of countries. I'm trying to eliminate the numerics,eg., Switzerland17 to Switzerland and also the brackets, eg., Bolivia (.. to Bolivia.

the code I have worked for the numeric cases such as Switzerland17 but not for the brackets:

```
for cty in energy['Country']:
    try:
        y = re.findall('[0-9]',cty)[0]
        energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(cty,cty[:cty.find(str(y))])
    except:
        continue
```

and this above works, however the below doesn't:

```
for c in energy['Country']:
    try:
        z = re.search('[(]',c)[0]
        energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(c,c[:c.find(str(z))])
    except:
        continue
```

I also see that individual print(c,c[:c.find(str(z))]) works but doesn't work when in a for-loop. Where am I going wrong with the find and replace the bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.replace` & `str.strip`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ["Switzerland17", "Bolivia (KK)", "China"]})
df["Country"] = df["Country"].str.strip("0123456789").str.replace(r"(\(.*?\))", "").str.strip()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       Country
0  Switzerland
1      Bolivia
2        China
```